# What happens to the orientation of charge or charge density after conductor is removed from an electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Once a conductor is subjected to an electric field, the charges within the conductor orient themselves in a manner that produce their own internal electric field that cancel the external applied electric field.

Any excess charges settle on the surface, which implies that the electric field within the conductor amounts to zero.

But what happens when conductor is no longer subjected to the electric field do they go back to their earlier state9that is the state before electric field was applied) or reorient in some new fashion or do their distributions remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Summary

Since it is a conductor they go right back. If it was a material that could be polarized, certain dielectrics, there would be an effect remaining, duration can vary a lot, see below:

But unlike conductors they affect the field while it’s there.

#### Polarization Remaining

The thing that makes the polarizing in an insulator [by an electric field] different from stretching an elastic body like a spring is that eliminating the stress doesn't necessarily release the strain. Some insulators will remain in their polarized state for hours, days, years, or even centuries.

From: https://physics.info/dielectrics/

#### Affecting the Field

Dielectric, insulating material or a very poor conductor of electric current. When dielectrics are placed in an electric field, practically no current flows in them because, unlike metals, they have no loosely bound, or free, electrons.. Instead, electric polarization occurs... This slight separation of charge, or polarization, reduces the electric field within the dielectric.

From: https://www.britannica.com/science/dielectric

#### More about Polarization

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/electric-polarization